# How to detect Fonts needed on a page and load necessary Fonts

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-chrome, fonts

I have a multi-author site, envolving 300+ writers. I provide them options to write their blogs in 25 Font Families. They can choose as many as they want in their post.

But to accomodate those 25 Google Fonts, I need a lot of CSS. I know that the font itself is downloaded by user agent, only if it is being used somewhere in HTML elements, but still the css required to just have those 25 fonts itself is really heavy too.

The stylesheet to add the fonts as provided by google even after minification is 180KB. You can check it at https://milyin.com/WPSE.css

180Kb can do lot of harm to performance for a site with cheap hosting like mine.

My Question is that is their any faster way to load the Google Fonts, such that the file isn't that big.

Or maybe a JS lib that can automatically load font whenever it finds it in site code.

Or some other approach..

The goal is to keep the site fast, while still allowing Authors to choose from 25 fonts.

Just so you know, when I enqueued the file, and waited for cache to rebuild and then checked my Google PSI, I saw over 15 points lost as an average, and page size increased significantly, now I stopped the enqueue till I find solution.

Note: As such if author doesn't use any font, then the entire page defaults to Locally Hosted Poppins font, which doesn't impact performance.

Comment: Many of the fonts look almost the same. If one don't see them next to each other he wouldn't find any difference. Perhaps you could exclude at least half of the fonts.

On the other hand each font generates traffic, you cannot avoid that! My suggestion is to provide 2-3 well readable fonts to your users. Each of them could be bold and italic. No author would require more.

Comment: Well, I respect your opinion, and I totally  agree. Infact I myself have written 300+ blog posts, and used the default fonts. But I intend to build my site as a Social Media platform for Blogging, I wanna give them variety and creative freedom, for which Fonts are necessarity, some really vibrant calligraphic and different looking fonts were choosen, (minimizing similar fonts) yet the number of fonts is till around 10... Still 65kb of css that I hope can be implemented differently. :-p

Comment: I'm still thinking how I could help you:)

Since the fonts are not downloaded until they are used, maybe the trick is to have 25 fonts available but to allow each author use only 2 or 3. Do you think this sounds better?

Comment: Yes.. That's very true, the problem is not font loading. The problem is css... the css file generated by Google Fonts responsible for loadings the fonts is 180Kb... which is way to much... I know that only 2 fonts are used usually by users... But you never know which 2 out of those 25 fonts will the author need, so i have to enqueue file having all 25 fonts even if user needs only 2, and that file is heavy. If their could be a way to find fonts needed via JS or PHP, then we could simply enqueue the css for only necessary font. But couldn't find a JS lib or PHP snippet for the same